# jsf: Passing arguments to method in backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I need to pass an argument like #{bean.userProfile} to a method like clear(UserProfile profile) in the backing bean.

```
<a4j:commandButton  value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('id_up')}.hide()"  execute="@this" type="reset" action="#{profilesBean.clear()}" render="id_panel">
```

I'm looking for the syntax for writing something like this in the action:

```
 action="#{profilesBean.clear(#profilesBean.selectedProfile)}"
```

I need to send all userProfile attributes via "selectedProfile".

Comment: action="#{profilesBean.clear(profilesBean.selectedProfile)}" should "just work" actually, assuming it is JSF 2 or higher. But if its the same bean (profilesBean) then why would you need to send it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If you use EL2.2 then you can use very similar syntax as you expected (second # should be removed):

```
action="#{profilesBean.clear(profilesBean.selectedProfile)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to pass parameter from jsf page to backingBean, i usually use this way:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{profilesBean.clear}" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profilesBean.selectedProfile}" value="#{profilesBean.userProfile}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

you can find the other ways in [mkyong site](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
<h:commandButton action="#{profilesBean.clear}">
    <f:param name="selectedProfile" value="selectedProfile" />
</h:commandButton>
```

and corrosponding bean

```
 public String clear() {

  Map<String,String> params = 
            FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
  String action = params.get("selectedProfile");
      //...

}
```